# How to get every disk in Windows and filter on DeviceType and then add the size of the disk next to it, separated by a comma?

Tags: windows, powershell, foreach

I'm writing an PowerShell script to collect some data of a computer. I'm almost done, but I don't know how to get size of all the disks on the computer. I know how to do it with a couple of If statements, but I want it to automatically detect the drives, not that I have to write a new If statement if a new disk is attached. The output I want is as follows: "A:,250GB". The "A:," bit works, but not the disk size bit.

This is the code I used and tweaked, but to no avail:

```
$Drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk| ?{$_.DriveType -eq 3} | ForEach-Object {$_.name}
ForEach ($Drivename in $Drives) {
    $Drivenames = Get-WMIObject -Query "Select * From win32_logicaldisk Where DriveType = '3'" -computer localhost | Select-Object DeviceID               
    $Drive = [Math]::Round($Drivenames.Size / 1GB)
    "$Drivenames,", $Drive | Out-File "C:\HDS\HDS_DRIVES.csv" -Append
}
```

In addition, `[Math]::Round($Drivenames.Size / 1GB)` throws me an error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'"

Comment: Forgot to mention, the "[Math]::Round($Drivenames.Size / 1GB)" bit, throws me an error: "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'"

Comment: `| Select-Object DeviceID` removes all other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Calculated Property with `Select-Object` to make it much more simple:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk| ? {$_.DriveType -eq 3} | 
Select-Object @{N="DeviceId";E={$_.DeviceId}},`
@{N="VolumeName";E={$_.VolumeName}},`
@{N="Size";E={[Math]::Round($_.Size / 1GB)}} | 
Out-File "C:\HDS\HDS_DRIVES.csv" -Append
```

Note that you don't need to Invoke `Get-WmiObject` Twice like in your example.

Comment: Alright, I tried your proposed solution, and it worked after I changed a few things. I'll mark this as the answer. Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

#### Why it doesn't work?

The issue is that `$Drivenames` contains only `DeviceID` (as you used `Select-Object` to get only that property). Therefore you're getting an error where trying to round it (as rounding nothing is not supposed to work).

#### How to fix it?

You have to add `Size` and then access it using `.PropertyName`:

```
$DriveInfo = Get-WMIObject -Query "Select * From win32_logicaldisk Where DriveType = '3'" -computer localhost | Select-Object DeviceID, Size
$DriveInfo | ForEach-Object {
 $DriveSize = [Math]::Round($_.Size / 1GB)
 "$($_.DeviceID),$DriveSize" | Out-File "C:\HDS\HDS_DRIVES.csv" -Append 
}
```

#### How can I make it more elegant

Also, take a look at [@Avshalom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653852/9902555) which uses calculated property.

Comment: Tried your, but it still fails with the same error I mentioned above. Tried @Avshalom's solution, and his solution worked.

Comment: Indeed I used incorrect variable for size. I already corrected it and it's giving me correct results. Please check once again if you want to, I tested on my side and it works. Btw, don't forget to upvote Avshalom's answer :)

Comment: Ok, figured it out, it was failing for multiple disks. Fixed